# https://userName:password@URL. does not work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to auto-populate the username and password in a pop-up window in chrome when first arriving on a webpage.

I have tried

```
https://userName:password@URL.
```

and

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("userName" + Keys.TAB + "password");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

and

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
    alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(promptName, password));
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is it a window alert or an HTML popup?

Comment: @aksappy- window alert

Comment: Such authentication method is no longer supported in browsers. Use proxy to [add authentication header to your requests](https://www.webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization).

Comment: Try Robot framework.

Comment: Thank you for all you suggestions, in the end I created an extension to combat the basic Auth.